# The referenced component 'ceTe.DynamicPDF.40' could not be found in VS Source Control

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to debug a web app in VS Source Control. But, I am getting the error

```
The type or namespace name 'ceTe' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The referenced component 'ceTe.DynamicPDF.40' could not be found
```

On expanding the References folder in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio, ceTe.DynamicPDF.40 is listed but marked with a yellow warning icon.

How do I fix this? I referred to this [Refrenced Toolkit could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655345/the-referenced-component-microsoft-phone-controls-toolkit-could-not-be-found) question but my problem is with the source control code. I do not have the related dll in my local repository of the project so I can't add it's reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by copying over the respective dll file from the server.

Comment: I am glad that your problem has been solved. You can mark it as answer so that others can solve the similar problem if they face it.

Comment: Sure @JackJJun-MSFT but the website will allow me to accept it as an answer tomorrow only.